# How could I change google drive folder in "C:/User Name/Google Drive" to somewhere else

Tags: google-drive-api

I've installed google drive app on my windows. How could I change custom folder in "C:/User Name/Google Drive" to somewhere else and how to sync it.

Comment: this is the not the right place for this question

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Change the Google Drive default folder**

*Use this tip to change the default folder location in Windows*

1. Click on **the Google Drive icon** in your system tray
2. Choose Quit Google Drive
3. Now move the Google Drive folder within Windows Explorer to a new location
4. **Restart** Google Drive from Start --> All Programs
5. Google Drive will warn you that it can't find the folder, click on the Google Drive icon again and choose Error - Google Drive folder is missing
6. A window will open up, choose Locate folder and go find the new Google Drive folder.

[Source](http://gappstips.com/docs-tips/view/106/change-the-google-drive-default-folder)

***SOLUTION SUGGESSTED BY David Trezeguet :***

*(Because I cannot add a comment, so I posted here)

- THE SECOND WAY TO CHANGE THE DEFAULT GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER IN WINDOWS: 4

  1. Click on **the Google Drive icon** in your system tray
  2. Choose **Disconnect account...** in *Preferences*
  3. Sign in again. You can change the folder when you click **Advanced setup** button.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, google claims "this is not your original google drive folder"

Comment: I got the same error as deltree ("This is not your original Google Drive folder!"), so I used the following steps to change the directory: Your 1st and 2nd step, then I deleted the directory as 3rd step. I restarted Google Drive as in your 4th step and then I disconnected the account. Finally I connected it to my account again by entering the credentials and I choose `Advanced Setup` mode to change the directory. After that, it will start downloading everything you've selected for sync. That's it :)

Comment: Doesn't work, once finished it immediately started re-downloading everything, attaching the suffix (1) to each file (because there was already a copy with the same name in the folder). What a waste of time.

Comment: when i post this solution it worked , now there is another solution , there is no need to downvote :)

Comment: I get Error:invalid root_inodes set([]) with no option to fix it.

Comment: The first suggested solution must be done with care. If by mistake you leave the original folder there with hidden files, for example, and not completely remove it, then Google Drive may think you have deleted all your files and delete them from the cloud as well! Therefore I recommend the 2nd method. It's safer.

Comment: The second method still works. Just sign out and discnnect account before the drive starts syncing. The second time you login, it will ask you for a drive folder!

Comment: First solution works well for `Backup and Sync from Google` too.